# Application Crash due to window error

Tags: windows, crash

I run a Windows application which suddenly crashes in between since last week.

It shows following error:

```
Description:
  Stopped working
```

The following Windows Event is logged in the Event Viewer:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: abc.exe
  Application Version:  1.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    510fbb25
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.18015
  Fault Module Timestamp:   50b8479b
  Exception Code:   e053534f
  Exception Offset: 0000000000009e5d
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.274.10
  Locale ID:    1033

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

The system OS is Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Did you write that application?

Comment: Can you share the part of the source code for abc.exe that is failing? If not, you've come to the wrong place, I'm afraid. "[Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them...](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)"

Comment: In my error log I get.this: "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted".....Is this helpful to you..??

Comment: It doesn't help much. Can you share the code?

Answer (score 0):

downgrade from .net framework 4.7.2 or 4.8 to 4.6.2